# Ubuntu 20.04 - Black Screen Issue for Old User

Tags: 20.04, login, gui

Got two users for my ubuntu machine: Main account and test account respectively

Via GUI, I get black screen post the login screen for my main account which has all tools installed from VPN etc
Whilst I'm successfully able to reach the ubuntu desktop with my test account.

I wanted to know what files on the .config or .cache on my main account could be causing this ?